# Start picture at the absolute top-left edge of the paper

Tags: diagrams, minipage, coordinates

I'm trying to get a layout done for a title page, but I can't get the coordinate raster correctly. For the record, I am **NOT** trying to create a grid, I need to place logos etc on a title page in exact positions according to a grid I was given. So no cm, no inches, no eso-pic grids, none of that.

I want a `picture` to start at position 0,0 at the absolute top left. So I tried the following in Latex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside, openright]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
      \newgeometry{margin = 0cm, headsep = 0cm, top = 0cm}
      \setlength{\unitlength}{10.6mm}
      \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{picture}(0,0)(0,0)
        \multiput(0,0)(0,-1){28}{\line(1,0){20}}
         \end{picture}      
      \end{titlepage}
      \restoregeometry


    }
\AtBeginDocument{
    \maketitle
    }

\begin{document}
No content
\end{document}
```

But when I look at the result, the first line still starts a little under the paper edge and a little to the right. So even with setting everything to 0, I can't place a bounding box that starts exactly at the top left corner of the paper.

What am I overlooking?

Alternatively: If there's a better way to specify a **coordinate system** of 28 squares along the long side and 20 squares along the short side of a paper, very welcome. This is the raster I'm after:

[image]

But this is the raster I get to see. Note the little edge on the left and top:

[image]

Important note: Obviously those lines are not part of the design. But I need a coordinate system that allows me to translate the very strict raster positions of all elements on the title page. And those lines show me that the coordinate system I have now, is not fulfilling these conditions.

Comment: Are you trying to create a grid?

Comment: I'd suggest `\usepackage[grid,gridunit=in]{eso-pic}` which will show you a grid on each page in `in`ches (you can change this to `cm` or whatever). Then you can use [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic)'s placement macros to just affect content on the title page using the grid. Once you're done, remove the `grid` option.

Comment: @azetina No, I'm trying to create a coordinate system that allows me to say "this logo has to start in box 4 from the top and box 7 from the left, this log has to start in box 11 from the top and box 2 from the left" and so on. I'm actually trying to make a title page for our students according to the layout guidelines of our university. The only template they have, is a Word template...

Comment: @Werner Tried it. That grid has the exact same problem: it doesn't start at the edge of the paper. I really need it to start at the edge of the paper (as the bounding box of some elements need to be set to the exact edge of the paper as well).

Comment: When you say "the paper" do you mean the image as seen in your PDF previewer, or the paper coming out of your printer?  Many printers are not very precise about where the image actually goes. Some printer drivers may helpfully shrink an image to fit the borders of the physical printing mechanism.

Comment: @Thruston I start with the PDF previewer. I took the precautions to make sure the PDF has the correct dimensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick answer: you have forgotten that you have the indentation box at the left of your `picture` and the `\topskip` glue above it.  Quick fix:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside, openright]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
      \newgeometry{margin = 0cm, headsep = 0cm, top = 0cm}
      \setlength{\unitlength}{10.6mm}
      \begin{titlepage}
        \topskip = 0pt % added
        \noindent      % added
        \begin{picture}(0,0)(0,0)
        \multiput(0,0)(0,-1){28}{\line(1,0){20}}
         \end{picture}      
      \end{titlepage}
      \restoregeometry


    }
\AtBeginDocument{
    \maketitle
    }

\begin{document}
No content.  Now \( \verb|\topskip| = \texttt{\the\topskip} \).
\end{document}
```

Comment: `topskip` did the trick (found `\noindent` already). I knew I was forgetting something obvious. Thank you very much!